# Accuracy of suggested edits review

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

Is it possible to find the accuracy of my suggested edit reviews, i.e. the volume of my approved/rejected edits that were finally approved/rejected by the community members? Or more importantly, is it possible to find my disputed reviews, i.e. I approved/rejected but it got rejected/approved?

To clarify more, say I have approved `x` edits, rejected `y` edits. Now `m` among `x` are finally approved, `n` are finally rejected. So my accuracy is:

`(m + n) / (x + y)`

Let me give an example. Say I have done total 10 reviews, and 8 of them match the community decision. So accuracy is 80%.

I know that I can check from my profile one-by-one, but is there any better way?

I think finding this in an easy way will help me to improve my review quality.

Comment: starred. When I get home, I'll see if I can write a userscript that doesn't flood the server with requests.

Comment: This is a great request, but phrasing what you want as "accuracy" seems a bit too much of a bow toward conformity.  How about "concurrence" or "concurrence rate"...or for the opposite value, taking a page from judge votes, "dissent rate"?  (somewhat related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissent_aversion)

Comment: A.M. is right. Just because your review differ from the majority, it doesn't necessarily mean that you are wrong. So "accuracy" isn't really the right word to use here.

Comment: Yes, I agree that being different from majority does not always mean wrong. One could think an edit "too minor" but others may not think such. So no one should expect 100%. But if my accuracy is significantly low, e.g. if less than 50%, then probably something is wrong with me. In that case may be I failed to understand the view of the community. That's why I guess it will be nice to have such stats.

Comment: I have mostly stopped reviewing edits, as by the time I have decided if the edit should be rejected, other people have approved it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in [Kate's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216445/238586), many edits that get approved should actually get rejected.

I made a query that shows you how many times you approved and the edit got approved, you rejected but the edit got approved, you approved but the edit got rejected, and you rejected and the edit got rejected. You can see and run that query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/160352/your-edit-reviews).

I also made [another query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/160347/your-supposedly-incorrect-suggested-edit-reviews) that links you to edits that you approved, but the edit got rejected.

EDIT: Gilles made some better queries here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216463/238586

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), which gives read-only access to a copy of a part of the Stack Exchange database. Suggested edit votes are included in the copy. The copy is currently updated weekly, so the most recent items won't be there yet.

- [Contested suggested edit reviews](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79860/my-contested-suggested-edit-reviews) (at least one reviewer's opinion differed from yours)
- [Overruled suggested edit reviews](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79859/my-overruled-suggested-edit-reviews) (the deciding vote went the other way from you)
- [Suggested edits that I approved but were rejected](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/159298/suggested-edits-that-i-approved-but-were-rejected) (subset of the previous one)

Answer (score 3):

The problem of robo reviewers still exists. These people are whipping through the queue as fast as they can to get a badge. It's quicker to Approve than to Reject (because to Reject you have to pick a reason) so they run through Approve, Approve, Approve, Approve. The stat you want would probably be very similar to your percentage of Approve votes.

To evaluate yourself as a reviewer, I suggest taking a look at the history tab in the review queue, and clicking on the word Accept or Reject next to posts you reviewed:

[image: Suggested Edit history]

This will show you how others voted on that post:

[image: Reviewers]

You can also get here from your activity list. On your profile go to the activity tab, and then reviews, and again click Approve or Reject:

[image]

Especially if you Approve when others Reject, take a good look at their reasons. If you Reject while others Approve, there's a chance you're the one who's actually right.

Comment: Actually, this is what I tried to do at the beginning. But as the number of reviews increased it became difficult to track all manually. That's why I was searching for a tool which would give me a quick stat. So far I have approved 163 edit suggestions and rejected 166 edit suggestions. My main concern is whether I am rejecting too much and doing injustice to people who suggested the edit.

Comment: Looking through your edits shows a problem with this stat: when you reject an audit, there's no-one to agree with, but you're right. When you Approve, but Community rejects because of an edit conflict, you are not necessarily wrong or right. This could become very difficult to code - and then when it's coded, you still don't know if you were the one lone voice of sanity in a sea of robo reviewers. I think it's great you want to be a good edit reviewer. If you weren't one, I believe you would have been told so by now. Relax and thanks for helping to operate the site.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I understand that it will be very difficult to detect whether someone is "one lone voice of sanity in a sea of robo reviewers" :-).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let me say that I think it would be a nice feature to have. Some people enjoy seeing all sorts of stats. Just like when you're watching ESPN or a televised sports game, and they state some stat like *"this third basemen has 5 throwing errors to first base (2 of which were on perfectly sunny days), 8 throwing errors to home plate (7 of which occurred during rain) and has only 1 error on throws to second base."* I become shocked that they actually keep all those stats.

However, major league sports leagues have access to a lot of money, resources, in that they can provide all these stats. The stats they collect don't ruin the play of the game.

Yes, stack exchange has the ability to do this as well. However, it would affect the ability of the website itself. Such as slower load times. And no one wants slower page load times.

Also, once you hit 2000 reputation points, every edit you make is automatically approved. So your edit %, *not counting the edits you made when you had below 2000 rep*, is always 100%, unless someone roll's back your edit. Which I believe happens very rarely to people that try to do a good job editing posts.

Comment: Sorry to say, but I think you got my question wrong. First, I was not asking about the edit suggestions that I made as <2k user. I was asking about my reviewer stat, i.e. the edit suggestions that I myself have reviewed. And second, if I do lots of wrong reviews then probably I am doing injustice to people who suggested the edit. This is not about enjoying stats, this is about improving myself as a reviewer. Please see my comment in the question.