# Stats on what proportion of my review decisions match the review outcome

Tags: feature-request, support, review, statistics

I have tried to dig around for this, but I can't find a way (other than stepping one by one through past reviews) to see what proportion of my review decisions match the eventual outcome of the review.

This stat would give me confidence that I'm in line with the review guidance and not becoming too lenient in my old age. If it gets too low, I can then double check individual reviews to find out why I'm missing the mark.

Comment: There is a Data Explorer query for this by @Gilles, let me find it. EDIT: [here it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186835/accuracy-of-suggested-edits-review/216463#216463).

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy that's useful, thanks. Actually it makes me realise it might not be a perfect answer as the results will be skewed for any reviews where I am the only one making the effort to properly review. Probably bettwe just to step through my past 'n' review results now and then.

Comment: I've a userscript [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508/158100) that shows the match/mismatch in your review history.