# How can I know how if I have been reviewing correctly?

Tags: support, review, review-audits

A while back, I had an audit failure, a right one at that. So, that prompted me to ask this question. On the same lines, in general, how do I know how I have been doing at reviews ? I can see the 'all actions' log on my profile, but is there a way to know how those fared, how peers reviewed what I reviewed and some indicator of this review was reasonable ?

Comment: @rene : Could you please post your comment as an answer, so I could mark it as valid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the [answer from HDE 226868](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268951/158100) you can do this by visiting the history tab of any review queue. From that UI you open each individual review to see how you did.

There is a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248338/adding-the-consensus-to-reviews-history/251508#251508) to add functionality to the history view to indicate the consensus between reviewers.

In the 6 to 8 weeks it will take to get that feature implemented you can use the userscript I wrote that mimics said feature request.

You can find the source code and details of its workings [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508/158100) or don't be bothered and install directly from [Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/9996-match-against-peers-in-review)

Answer (score 3):

"Reviewing correctly" is hard to quantify, because on some cases, reviewing can be subjective. There are guidelines for on-topic-ness/off-topic-ness and the like, but there are grey areas, too. Review audits are designed to be non-controversial and tests of "roboreviewers" who simply click buttons without thinking, but there are cases where an audit isn't really "correct", for lack of a better word.

You can see what other people did when reviewing the same post as you (this is only after reviewing the post, though) (identifying information removed):

[image]

You'll see the post, its votes, its status, when you reviewed it, who else reviewed it and what they said, and other information.

Once you reach [10k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (2k on beta sites), you can review *all* reviews.