# Show the fate of the suggested edit in the history tab

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

When going to [/review/suggested-edits/history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history), you see a list of suggested edits, like this (if you have 10k rep/a diamond, otherwise you only see what you reviewed):

[image: suggested edit on...]

It says 'suggested edit on XXXXX'. But it would be more useful if you could see the fate of the suggested edit there, instead, like it shows when you look at what someone suggested:

[image: suggested pending edit/suggested approved edit]

So then the /history tab would show something like this:

[image: rejected edit on xxx, approved edit on xxxx]

This would make it easier to see what the fate of the edit was, instead of counting reviews.

<sub>"Okay, this got... hmm.. one approve, one reject - where's the other review? - ah, here it is. Okay, that was rejected."</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I disagree with this request.

The history page of suggested edits is showing the history of **each review action**, not of every suggested edit.

Each row in the table is a review action done by a user, and not a review item as in users profile, and that is a big difference.

Showing the status of each review *item* in there will be wrong in my opinion.

The "fate" of each review item is one click away, and if your goal is to  get stats, userscript can do the job just fine, or SEDE.

Comment: [This userscript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508/158100)?

Comment: @rene yup, exactly. this.