# Is a question that asks for a review of my reviews allowed on Meta?

Tags: support, review, meta, scope, review-suspension

I'd like to ask for a review of my reviews, as I've just been banned for the first time. Is that a valid question here?

Comment: You should ask it on the site where you're review banned.

Comment: ah, yes. I'll ask it at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I wrote a script [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248338/adding-the-consensus-to-reviews-history/251508#251508) that allows you to check how you reviewed against others. That can help to find the reviews you might want to revisit and/or discuss.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, but not *this* Meta.

Questions about contents (including reviews) on a site is totally on-topic on its *per-site meta*, in your case, [Meta Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com).

Well, this site also starts with "Meta", but not the right place. But at least I'm glad that you know there's something called "a meta site" for issues like this.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the per-site meta on whatever site you were banned on and ask about the reviews that got you banned. Review bans are specific to the site they occurred on and would probably be closed here as "only applicable to one specific site".

Comment: Ok, but I think an option to talk with the mods is very missing from the system.